# python - This part makes the code repeat twice, how can I fix it

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```py
import discord

embed = discord.Embed()

for x in my_list:
    for y in New_list:
        embed.add_field(name=f'{x}', value=f'{y}', inline=False)
```

When I turn the bot on and run this it sends `x` and `y` twice and I can't think of a solution.

Comment: provide an example of `my_list` and `New_list`. Provide an example of an actual current output and an example of your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are added fields to your [`embed`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#embed) when looping through `my_list` and then through `New_list`.

For the example, let's say that:

```py
my_list = ["a", "b"]
New_list = ["c", "d"]
```

- Firstly, `x` will be equal to `"a"` and `y` to `"c"`, so the embed will add the field of name `"a"` and value `"c"`.
- Then, `x` will still be `"a"` and `y` will be equal to `"d"`, so the embed will add the field of name `"a"` and value `"d"`.
- Then, `x` will be equal to `"b"` and `y` to `"c"`, so the embed will add the field of name `"b"` and value `"c"`.
- Finally, `x` will be equal to `"b"` and `y` to `"d"`, so the embed will add the field of name `"b"` and value `"d"`.

If you only want to add one embed field of name `"a"` and value `"c"`, and one of name `"b"` and value `"d"`, you will need to use the built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```py
import discord

my_list = ["a", "b"]
New_list = ["c", "d"]

embed = discord.Embed()

for x, y in zip(my_list, New_list):
    embed.add_field(name=f'{x}', value=f'{y}', inline=False)
```